# How to attach an image file to text message using SmsManager in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have been searching for information here at Stackoverflow and via Google on how to attach image file using SmsManager.  I can send text message using the following code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

However, I couldn't get any hint on how to attache image file with the above code. I see that there is `smsManager.sendMeltimediaMessage`but I do not know how to implement this to send text message with image file (mine is jpg file). I can access the image path easily with `txtPath.getText().toString();`

All I need is to send a text message with the attachment using SmsManager that consists of receiver's nr, text message, and image attachment. I don't want to receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

use this amazing library to send media through sms https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms

Comment: The above link doesn't open. Plus, could you provide me with the information if it uses SmsManager or not. If yes, could you drop the lines of the code that is functional to send text message with the image attachment ?

Comment: check the link now

Comment: Naveed, that link is not in the requirement I asked in my question. Please re-read my question.